# HikariDataSource : HikariPool-0 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms

Tags: sql, oracle, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I am working on a springboot application which contains two database connections..

one is Mysql and another is Oracle..There is no problem with the Mysql connections and datasource bean(MariaDB)..but when it comes to Oracle(which is a external database deployed in Cloud Foundry) There are problems.

my CloudConfig file looks like this,

```
private DataSource createDataSource(final String serviceName, final Cloud cloud) {
        final ExternalDependency externalDependency = cloud
                .getServiceConnector(serviceName, ExternalDependency.class, null);
        if (externalDependency == null) {
            throw new InvalidConfigurationException(
                    String.format("Error getting ServiceConnector for External Dependency with serviceName=[%s]", serviceName)
                    );
        }
        HikariDataSource dataSource = null;

        try {
            final HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
            config.setDriverClassName(requiredStringProperty("driverClassName", externalDependency, serviceName));
            config.setJdbcUrl(requiredStringProperty("jdbcUrl", externalDependency, serviceName));
            config.setUsername(requiredStringProperty("username", externalDependency, serviceName));
            config.setPassword(requiredStringProperty("password", externalDependency, serviceName));
            config.setConnectionTestQuery(requiredStringProperty("connectionTestQuery", externalDependency, serviceName));
            config.setMinimumIdle(intProperty("minimumIdle", externalDependency, serviceName, 1));
            config.setMaximumPoolSize(intProperty("maximumPoolSize", externalDependency, serviceName, 5));

            LOG.info("config values : {}, {}, {} ,{}, {}, {}, {}", 
                    config.getDriverClassName(), 
                    config.getJdbcUrl(), 
                    config.getUsername(), 
                    config.getPassword(), 
                    config.getConnectionTestQuery(),
                    config.getMinimumIdle(), 
                    config.getMaximumPoolSize());

            LOG.info("Before HikariDatasource");
            dataSource = new HikariDataSource(config);
            LOG.info("After HikariDatasource");

            /*OracleDataSource dataSource1 = new OracleDataSource();

            dataSsetDriverClassName(requiredStringProperty("driverClassName", externalDependency, serviceName));
            dataSource1.setJdbcUrl(requiredStringProperty("jdbcUrl", externalDependency, serviceName));
            dataSource1.setUsername(requiredStringProperty("username", externalDependency, serviceName));
            dataSource.
            */
            String dataSourceDetails = dataSourceDetails(dataSource);
            LOG.info("Available DataSource oracleDb: [{}]", dataSourceDetails);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            LOG.info("Info For The Error : {}", e.getMessage());

            LOG.info("{}", e);
        }
        return dataSource;
```

I am able to get all the details..i have checked with all connections ..they ae running fine.

but when i deploy the jar in cloud foundry i get this below issue, please find the stack trace below,

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-0 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.
2018-10-17T16:45:10.290+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:196) ~[HikariCP-2.4.2.jar!/:na]
2018-10-17T16:45:10.290+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:148) ~[HikariCP-2.4.2.jar!/:na]
2018-10-17T16:45:10.290+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.initializeConnections(HikariPool.java:519) ~[HikariCP-2.4.2.jar!/:na]
2018-10-17T16:45:10.290+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ... 122 common frames omitted
2018-10-17T16:45:10.290+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
2018-10-17T16:45:10.291+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:774) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar!/:12.2.0.1.0]
2018-10-17T16:45:10.291+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:688) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar!/:12.2.0.1.0]
```

Can someone please help ? i am stuck with this issue from 2 days!!

Comment: How you are passing oracle DB service credentails to the application ?. have you tried using simple app with DataSourceAutoConfiguration that you are able to connect to oracle DB ? Did you test the connectivity from cloud foundry to oracle ? it looks like it is unable to connect to oracle DB from the container. Do an ssh into the contianer like cf ssh   app-name, then do a ping to oracle host

Comment: Looks like a networking error. Check that you can connect from inside the app container on CF. You might have an application security group which is blocking access, so you might need to get your operator to adjust that for you. Try `cf ssh` to an app on the platform, doesn't matter which one, then run `nc -v <oracle-host> <oracle-port>`. That should test making a TCP connection to Oracle. If it fails to connect, you have network problem.